# Rendering a Heterogeneous Collection: How can I specify a single directory for the partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, partial-views, render

I have a collection, @comments, that is heterogeneous but hierarchical.  Each comment is either an instance of Comment or some derived class, like ActionComment or InactionComment.  I am rendering a different partial for each type of Comment.  The View code is:

`= render @comments`

As all the partials are related, I would like to keep them in a single view directory, i.e.:

- app/views/comments/_comment.haml
- app/views/comments/_action_comment.haml
- app/views/comments/_inaction_comment.haml

But right now in order to use the automatic rendering of the correct partial, I am using separate directories, like:

- app/views/comments/_comment.haml
- app/views/action_comments/_action_comment.haml
- app/views/inaction_comments/_inaction_comment.haml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 3.2 makes a Model#to_partial_path method available which allows you (as its name suggests) to override the partial pathname.

```
  def to_partial_path
    self.action.to_s
  end
```

The path it returns does not include the leading underscore and is assumed to be relative to `.../views/modelname/`.  See http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/01/my-five-favorite-hidden-features-in-rails-3-2/ for an overview

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it quite as magically, but you can do it by just rendering each item individually and specifying the partial.

example in haml:

```
- @comments.each do |c|
  = render :partial => "comments/#{c.class.to_s.underscore}", :locals => {:comment => c}
```

Comment: This answer worked great for Rails < 3.2. I'm changing my accepted answer to be up-to-date with the current version of Rails.